# Using Perl to communicate with Nut

Tags: battery, perl, ups

I'm trying to communicate with my UPS that's managed using NUT. I want to read values from it like line voltage, battery charge, etc. I don't want to send it commands to shut it down.

At first I was going to mess around capturing the output of "upsc apc@remotehost" and parsing it with regexps.

... then I turned my brain on and had a look around CPAN and found the UPS::Nut module, except after trying it and realising it was last updated in 2002, it doesn't work with the latest version of NUT.

So is there a better way than parsing the output of *upsc* with regexps?

Comment: Use python. [PyNUT.py](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/blob/master/scripts/python/module/PyNUT.py) should be in the package, and there's also [nut2](https://github.com/rshipp/python-nut2).

Answer (score 0):

In PERL if you capture the output of one command in one big string , you should use  the flag `m` to match only a line with some pattern .

1. a very simple example with **perl**

```
my $upsc_output=`/bin/upsc qnapups\@qnap.local 2>&1` ;

my $bat_charge=( $upsc_output =~ /^battery\.charge: (.*)$/m)[0] ;
my $ups_status=( $upsc_output =~ /^ups\.status: (.*)$/m)[0] ;

printf("BAT_CHARGE %s\n",$bat_charge) ;
printf("UPS_STATUS %s\n",$ups_status) ;
```

2. a very simple example with **bash**

```
INFO_UPS=$(mktemp)
upsc qnapups@qnap.local > ${INFO_UPS} 2>/dev/null

BAT_CHARGE=$( grep '^battery\.charge:' $INFO_UPS | cut -d: -f2- )
UPS_STATUS=$( grep '^ups\.status:' $INFO_UPS | cut -d: -f2- )

printf 'BAT_CHARGE %s\n' "$BAT_CHARGE"
printf 'UPS_STATUS %s\n' "$UPS_STATUS"
```